# Shell eating `?` characters

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, special-characters

This is such a simple question that I'm sure it's been asked somewhere, but I can't find it.  My shell, which I have not intentionally set up to do so, seems to eat any words involving question marks:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ echo a ? = =?
a =

$ not-a-command? echo a
a

$ (?) echo a
a
```

In case it matters, note that *any* word containing a question mark seems to disappear completely silently—to the extent that she shell never even notices that the invocation starts with a word that doesn't specify a valid executable—even if the question mark is not at the beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have the `nullglob` shell option enabled; this causes any word containing a globbing character (`*` or `?`) to be removed if the glob doesn't match anything. Thus, if you're in a folder which doesn't contain any file, folder etc. with a single-character name, `?` won't expand to anything and will instead be removed; likewise, `not-a-command?` is unlikely to match anything and will instead be removed.

To check whether this is the case, run

```
shopt nullglob
```

To de-activate the option, run

```
shopt -u nullglob
```

Answer (score 2):

it's like `*`, but it represents a single character

e.g. show the three-character root directories:

```
$ ls -d /???
/bin  /dev  /etc  /lib  /mnt  /opt  /run  /sys  /tmp  /usr  /var
```

note that `/home` is not shown because it doesn't match

Use `[?]` or `\?` or wrap your strings in quotation marks (`"foo?"` or `'bar?'`)