# list files or directory sorted in ascending order

Tags: bash, files

How do we, by `ls` or other shell commands, list files or directory sorted in ascending lexicographical order without differentiating the letter case so that it's shown in the order of continues true alphabet order

Comment: My `ls` does exactly that. Doesn't yours?

Comment: Perhaps related [Sort files alphabetically with ls on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406394/sort-files-alphabetically-with-ls-on-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior of ls, if this is not how ls is behaving for you than you then ls is probably aliased with some options in your ~/.bashrc file.

[image: ls default sorting]