# Emacs dired list .(dot) ..(dotdot) first

Tags: ls, emacs, dot-files

In short, how do I implement the solution in following question in emacs for use in dired? I cannot comment there, so I started this question.

[How can I make “ls” show dotfiles first while staying case-insensitive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288333/how-can-i-make-ls-show-dotfiles-first-while-staying-case-insensitive/361006#361006)

The longer version: In emacs dired, I want to always list . and .. as the first two entries. Right now, I used following:

`(setq dired-listing-switches "-aFl --group-directories-first -v ")`

However, it puts the directory (1dir) at the very end. This is not what I want, as my GUI file manager puts them the first and this causes confusion. The solution in above question solved the issue for me under terminal as illustrated in following.

Is there a way to implement this solution in emacs dired?

```
>  mkdir -p .dotdir dir \(1dir\)
>  touch .dotfile file \(2file\)
>  ls -lFa --group-directories-first
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 myusr myusr 4096 Dec 22 11:04 '(1dir)'/
drwxr-xr-x 1 myusr myusr 4096 Dec 22 11:05  ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 root  root  4096 Dec 11 12:16  ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 myusr myusr 4096 Dec 22 11:04  .dotdir/
drwxr-xr-x 1 myusr myusr 4096 Dec 22 11:04  dir/
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusr myusr    0 Dec 22 11:05 '(2file)'
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusr myusr    0 Dec 22 11:05  .dotfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusr myusr    0 Dec 22 11:05  file

>  LOCPATH=$HOME/.dotfiles/locales LANG=en_DOTFILE.UTF-8 ls -lFa --group-directories-first
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 myusr myusr 4096 Dec 22 11:05  ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 root  root  4096 Dec 11 12:16  ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 myusr myusr 4096 Dec 22 11:04  .dotdir/
drwxr-xr-x 1 myusr myusr 4096 Dec 22 11:04 '(1dir)'/
drwxr-xr-x 1 myusr myusr 4096 Dec 22 11:04  dir/
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusr myusr    0 Dec 22 11:05  .dotfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusr myusr    0 Dec 22 11:05 '(2file)'
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusr myusr    0 Dec 22 11:05  file
```

Comment: `(` sorts less than `.`, so you could need to rename the `(1dir)` to some `{1dir}`.